# Connection lost as soon as a connection is made - NodeJS/MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I've been having a problem for the past few days where my node application which requires a connection to be open for a little continuously crashes as soon as a connection is made. This problem came up all of a sudden after my application has been running completely fine for months. My VM crashed before this started happening and now I can't get the connection lost error to stop. My application and mySQL DB are hosted on the same server.

The error is:

```
 { Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Protocol.end (/root/OTB/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/OTB/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/OTB/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:1)
at emitNone (events.js:111:2)
at Socket.emit (events.js:28:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:164:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/root/OTB/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/root/OTB/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (/root/OTB/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
at Connection._implyConnect (/root/OTB/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:457:1)
at Connection.query (/root/OTB/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:199:8)
at Timeout.keepalive [as _onTimeout] (/root/OTB/appl.js:248:7)
at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:29:5) fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }
```

I'm already using a pool. I've tried catching the disconnect and trying to reconnect but it doesn't work because it just keeps crashing instantly. I really have no idea what's happening. I've increased the wait_timeout, interactive_timeout, and max connections. I've tried adding a keepalive function to keep the connection open but as I mentioned, the connection is instantly closed.

I'd really appreciate some guidance on what to try next, thank you.

Edit:
The Pool is simply:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
        host: "IP",
        user: "USER",
        password: "PASS",
        database: "sys"
    });
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
connection.query("SQLSTRING", function(err, result, fields) {
});
});
```

I also tried playing around with some parameters such as

```
        agent: false,
        connector: "mysql",
        connectTimeout  : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        aquireTimeout   : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        timeout         : 60 * 60 * 1000,
        pool: {maxConnections: 10000, maxIdleTime: 10000}
```

Edit2: Additional info

I may have found an issue with my code. It's very possible that I'm not really using connection pooling properly. So I have multiple functions that are making queries to my database, what's the correct way to be creating the connections?

I originally had a separate pool for each function being created which I believe is incorrect, but even with one single pool declaration outside of the functions and each function calling `pool.getConnection`, it also doesn't work. Is this the correct way? As I mentioned before though, this code has been working for months without issue.

Comment: Did anything change before the crash occurrences?

Comment: please provide your script so we can check if there's anything wrong, have you tried restarting the MySQL service?

Comment: I personally never changed anything. And I've tried restarting the VM, the service, everything. I edited my question with an example of my setup Cedric, it's the basic pool setup.

Comment: Also the reason for the server crash was unrelated, my server ran out of memory and crashed. After restarting all my applications, this is when I noticed this issue.

Comment: Could it be that some of the MySQL tables corrupted?

Comment: The tables are completely fine in this case thankfully.

Comment: Do you have any other MySQL connection you test with other than the one you're using now? Maybe a test server like that..

Comment: I don't have another server unfortunately :/

Comment: I'm not sure if its related but maybe you can refer this ? https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1977

Comment: I don't think this is related. However although I'm not entirely sure, I may have found an issue with my code. It's very possible that I'm not really using connection pooling properly. So I have multiple functions that are making queries to my database, what's the correct way to be creating the connections? I originally had a separate pool for each function being created which I believe is incorrect, but even with one single pool declaration outside of the functions and each function calling pool.getConnection, it also doesn't work. Is this the correct way?

Comment: I also tried having an external JS file with the pool being created there but that had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this two option, it might help.
1.

```
var connection;
    function connectDb() {
  connection  = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '--',
    database: '---',
    password: '----'
  });
  connection.on('error', connectDb()); // probably worth adding timeout / throttle / etc
}
```

2.

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: '--',
  database: '---',
  password: '----'
});

// ... later
pool.query('select 1 + 1', (err, rows) => { /* */ });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this had the same result. Thank you for the suggestions though